# TypeAhead - begins-with full text search

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm implementing a simple search in postgresql that will be used to retrieve typeahead results on a web page.  So, I need the last argument to use starts-with matching, since the user may not have finished typing the word.  When I construct my `tsquery`, I'm adding `:*` to the last argument.  Here's a sample query:

```
SELECT id, key, name
FROM principal,
     to_tsvector(key || ' ' || name) vector,
     to_tsquery('investig:*') query
WHERE vector @@ query
ORDER BY ts_rank(vector, query) DESC
```

While typing the word "investigate", I get the following behavior:

```
Input       | Result Count
==========================       
i           | 0
in          | 0
inv         | 8
inve        | 8
inves       | 8
invest      | 8
investi     | 7
investig    | 7
investiga   | 0
investigat  | 0
investigate | 7
```

This is better than if I omit the `:*`, but not good enough.  Why do I get 0 results for `investiga` when `investigate` returns 7 results?  Is there a better way to construct my query to make sure I get everything that begins with a search term?